# Migrate entire SQL Server Database into a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

I'm looking for advice on how to move an entire SQL database - with multiple linked tables into a Sharepoint site, with each table becoming its own list. I don't need them to sync, just to move all the data off the SQL database once. Is there a tool or feature that will ease this migration or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Do you want to keep the same structure and relationships?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep the same relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with couple of ways.

1. Export the SQL table data into Excel, then import that excel file into SharePoint list.
2. You can use 3rd party tools i.e [List Bulk Import](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-list-bulk-import.aspx)
3. You can think about the BCS using the external list.